# Number of complete graph components

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph. How do I check if it can be divided into two sets where every node of one set is connected to every other node of its own set (complete graph). A set can be empty or of only one node. No node should be remaining.
Thanks.

EDIT: Edges between two sets is not forbidden.

**Basically we have to check if the graph can be divided into two cliques**

Comment: Do you also forbid edges between the 2 sets?  (Your current phrasing *does not* forbid them.)  If so, this can easily be done in O(n^2) time for n vertices: Consider vertices in some order, and let i be the first vertex that does not have an edge to any earlier vertex (if it has edges to some but not all, the answer is NO).  Then every later vertex must be connected to either every vertex < i, or to every vertex >= i.

Comment: You have to be more specific, I think : your problem looks like a minimum (vertex)k-clique cover problem, but it is not clear if you want to find this cover and k, or if you just want to say if it is possible or not for k=2. Take also care to the fact that vertex clique cover and edge clique cover are very different in terms of parameterized complexity.

Comment: Yes, I just want to know if such two sets are possible or not. and every vertex should be in either one of those sets.

Comment: There is O(2^n * n^2) algorithm for this. If it is acceptable I can write an answer.

Comment: no, O(n^2) is expected.

Comment: This is part of an ongoing coding contest: https://www.codechef.com/SEPT16/problems/CHFNFRN.  Please don't ask us to solve contest problems for you.  And asking for outside help violates the rules of that contest.

Answer (score 5):

As commented by @Damien, checking whether vertices of a given graph can be partitioned into two cliques is actually the decision problem of [clique cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover) with k = 2. For general k (even for k = 3), the clique cover problem is known to be NP-complete. For k = 2, there exists a O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, based on the observation below.

> Given a graph G = (V, E), denote its complement as G'. Then V can be partitioned into two cliques if and only if G' is 2-colorable.

The proof is simple and thus omitted here. The sketch of the algorithm is shown below.

```
01. construct G' from G;
02. if G' is bipartite
03.   return true;
04. else
05.   return false;
```

Note that the first line requires O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, while testing whether G' is bipartite requires only O(n + m) time using BFS, where n is the # of vertices and m is the # of edges. Therefore, the total complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).